# Facebook fan page going immediately to wall after like, used to go back to the app

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

I use fan gates on a lot of different fan pages. The idea has always been you land on the page and see a like us to *gain something* after clicking like the page reloads and now the user sees the content behind the fan gate.

I noticed today that after liking a page it immediately goes to the wall, is this a bug? Is this feature deprecated? I don't have much wall activity on my pages, I'd rather users see our portfolio or special deals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug on facebook right now, described here - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/110015112440103

It'd be great to have an interim fix but since the code for the Like button is outside of what's accessible to the page tab, I'm having trouble imaging what a solution might look like, short of removing the address from your page to make it not a "place", which seem to be the only pages affected.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having this problem for the past few days, but today I found the solution. It seems the problem lies with the new recommend dialog box on pages. This box only appears on pages for places and prevents the page from reloading. If you have a address assigned to your page then remove it and your fangate will reload in the window when liked and not redirect to the wall page. I know this isn't a preferred fix, but until Facebook fixes the new dialog box it'll have to do.

Comment: This seems to be the issue in my case too, though I cant test it right now because it says adding an address will take few hours. But this is the reason that matches the most to my problem